# My Android Studio logcat is broken

Tags: android

So I've been trying to make an app and i don't know why but my Logcat looks like this and I don't know why!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNBVr.jpg

Comment: seems normal to me.. Those are just the device logs

Comment: doesn't look broken to me

Comment: well, shouldn't it show some errors when the app stops because of errors ? because it doesn't show anything, just this

Answer (score 0):

You have set your Log Level to `Error`, which makes that you only see the Errors your Phone had. Set the Shown LogLevel to `Verbose` to see everything which gets logged.

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering the Logcat messages, the Android studio should filter the messages automatically according to your package id, but if it doesn't, you can do it manually, in top right of your picture there is a drop down "Show only selected application", click on it and select "Edit Filter Configuration", then in "Package Name" , write the package name you set in AndroidManifest.xml, (the com.xxx.xxx in the below example)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.xxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.6.0.0" >
```

Comment: yeah thanks for that, but it doesn't show errors yet, don't know why

Comment: in some rare cases, the exception messages does not appear in logcat, I've experienced it myself when the vm exits so fast that there is no time to capture the exception message and stack trace. maybe you could try to debug your app, line by line and see where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `logcat`'s fault, but the ROM's. I've seen many smartphones, which, when running stock ROM's just spammed the `logcat` out.

You should use filters to distinguish messages from your app from the others.